# Call webservice at page load in AngularJS Framework scope

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, angularjs, web-services

I have a webservice which returns Jsonobject and I call it in JS using Ajax like here :

```
$scope.init = function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    timeout: 1000000000,
                    url: serverName.replace('services', 'servicesV2') + '/getTreasuryResults',
                    data: { data: 'None' }, // the data in form-encoded format, ie as it would appear on a querystring
                    dataType: "text", // the data type we want back, so text.  The data will come wrapped in xml
                    success: function (data) {
                        var dataAngularTreasury = JSON.parse(data);
                        alert(dataAngularTreasury);
                        //FillDefaultTreasuryValues(data.split(";"));
                        CallTreasuryDetailValuesWS(934);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert(errServiceCall); // show the string that was returned, this will be the data inside the xml wrapper
                        $('#loading').hide();
                    }
                });
            };
```

If I call that init() function in ng-click like

```
<button id="btnGetDefaultValues" type="button" class="button" ng-click="init()">Fill</button>
```

It runs with no problem.

but if I call this webservice in page load like

```
angular.module('termDeposite', []).controller('userCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.treasuryValues = [];


    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            timeout: 1000000000,
            url: serverName.replace('services', 'servicesV2') + '/getTreasuryResults',
            data: { data: 'None' }, // the data in form-encoded format, ie as it would appear on a querystring
            dataType: "text", // the data type we want back, so text.  The data will come wrapped in xml
            success: function (data) {
                var dataAngularTreasury = JSON.parse(data);
                alert(dataAngularTreasury);
                //FillDefaultTreasuryValues(data.split(";"));
                CallTreasuryDetailValuesWS(934);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(errServiceCall); // show the string that was returned, this will be the data inside the xml wrapper
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

or

if I call this webservice in ng-init trigger like

```
<body id="body" ng-app="termDeposite" ng-controller="userCtrl" ng-init="init()"  >
```

webservice goes to error step and throws that error :

> "\n\n\nError 404--Not
>   Found\n\n\n\n\n\n
>
> ### Error 404--Not
>   Found
>
> \n\n\n
>
> #### From RFC
>   2068 *Hypertext Transfer Protocol --
>   HTTP/1.1*:
>
> \n10.4.5 404 Not Found\n
>
> The server has not found anything matching the
>   Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is
>   temporary or permanent.
>
> If the server does not wish to make this
>   information available to the client, the status code 403 (Forbidden)
>   can be used instead. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the
>   server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an
>   old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding
>   address.
>
> \n\n\n\n\n\n"

Finally, I can call a webservice with using ng-click but I can't call same webservice using ng-init or pageload. So how can I call a webservice using ajax in page init or page load in angular framework scope ?

Comment: check using your browsers network tab or fiddler. are they making the exact same request?

Comment: Yeah I can call same webservice using copy full ws url and paste it to the browser tab directly, and it returns no error.

Comment: using .ready in controller does not make much sense

Comment: but i need that ws returned data in page load @YOU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have serverName as a global and it is readable then the ng-init version or creating a custom directive and sticking the code in the link function should work.

Check the URL that is actually being called in the network tab in the Chrome dev tools (built into chrome) - cmd+alt+j on mac f12 on PC.

Comment: it's about serverName. Thank you @alexrogins